# Android onDraw doesn't draw anything in custom TextView when setting singleLine to true

Tags: android, textview, android-custom-view

There is a bug when I set `singleLine` to `true` in the XML layout of my custom `TextView` in my project. I don't know how to fix it. Is there anyone who can help me?

[image: See the image]

[github link](https://github.com/H07000223/FlycoRoundView/issues)

Comment: what do you mean by that "doesn't draw anything"? call canvas.drawColor for example...

Comment: Set singleLine true for custom TextView cause custom draw invalid. You can see the issue in my project in github. [Here is Code](https://github.com/H07000223/FlycoRoundView/blob/master/FlycoRoundView_Lib/src/main/java/com/flyco/roundview/RoundTextView.java)

Comment: this issue cause a bug which cost 2 days!! I'm so unhappy

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I used `android:maxLines="1"` instead.