# Android onDraw doesn't draw anything in custom EditText

Tags: android-edittext, ondraw

[similar problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33828761/android-ondraw-doesnt-draw-anything-in-custom-textview-when-setting-singleline)

I have a Custom EditText:

```
public class MyEditText extends AppCompatEditText {

public MyEditText(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public MyEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    int width = getMeasuredWidth();
    int height = getMeasuredHeight();
    canvas.drawCircle(width / 2, height / 2, Math.min(width, height) / 2, getPaint());
}
```

}

in xml:

```
   <com.angcyo.myapplication.MyEditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"/>
```

Normal effect:

[effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQuuS.png)

But If you Simultaneous setting 
`android:gravity="right" android:inputType="text"`

like this:

```
<com.angcyo.myapplication.MyEditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:inputType="text"/>
```

Well, the result is...

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fjkdj.png)

What happened? doesn't draw anything?

Answer (score 0):

Try to extend EditText rather than AppCompatEditText. 
    And change getmeasuredHeight() and getmeasuredWidth()  to getHeight() and getWidth() then see.

Initialize Paint like 
Paint paint =new Paint(); paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
and change the radius to 50f or 60f in third parameter and then see.

Comment: @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        canvas.drawCircle(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2, 50f, paint);
    }           no effect...OMG

Comment: can you post the full xml?

Comment: <FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <com.angcyo.myapplication.MyEditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:text="Hello World!"/>

</FrameLayout>